# SQL: why we need transaction for ticket booking?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, transactions

I have read that transaction is usually used in movie ticket booking website, to solve concurrent purchase problem. However, I failed to understand why is it necessary.

If at the same time, 2 users book the same `seat (ID = 1)` on the same `show (ID = 99)`, can't you simply issue the following SQL command?

```sql
UPDATE seat_db
SET takenByUserID=someUserId
WHERE showID=99 AND seatID=1 AND takenByUserID IS NOT NULL
```

As I can see, this SQL is already been executed atomically, there's no concurrency issue. The database will **set** `seat ID=1` to 1st user of which the server receives the request, then let the 2nd user's request fail. So, why is transaction still needed for ticket booking system?

Comment: It's unusual to use an UPDATE in this scenario. An INSERT is more likely.

Comment: Why is that? When a show is created, we pre-generate all the seat rows in `seat_db` for this show. And when a seat is taken, set `takenByUserID` field for that seat row. Isn't this logical?

Comment: Maybe you do, but that's very unusual.

Answer (score 0):

When you batch all of your `DML` statements into a single transaction typically you are telling the database a couple things:

1. Make this operation (i.e. book movie ticket) an all-or-nothing operation

   - Ensure you don't leave any orphan rows and have consistent data
2. Lock all the associated tables up-front so that no other writes can be done while the operation runs

   - Prevents other transactions from modifying tables your current operation wants to access
   - Prevents deadlock and allows processing to continue by aborting one of the locking queries

Whether you need to wrap your `UPDATE seat_db` request in its own transaction depends on what other processing (`DML`) is being done before and after it.

Comment: However in a movie ticket scenario like the above, no transaction is necessary right?

Comment: Well, what other SQL statements are involved in the "book movie ticket" process?  Is it just this one single `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use transactions if your action involves multiple unrelated rows. For example, if the user has to pay for the ticket, then there will be at least two updates: update the user's credit and mark the seat as occupied. If any of the two updates were performed alone you'll definitely get into trouble.